# CodeIgniter cannot figure out the error Undefined variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is taking long to figure out.

The Error

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: galdata
>
> Filename: admin/slidersetting.php
>
> Line Number: 90

**The controller**

```
public function homesliderimage()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $galdata=$this->homecontentmodel->fetchsliderimg();
    $this->load->view('admin/slidersetting',['galdata'=>$galdata]);
}
```

The View

```
    if(count($galdata)){
            foreach($galdata as $gallerydata){
                ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $gallerydata->id?>" src="<?php echo base_url().'/'.$gallerydata->bgimagepath;?>" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
            <div id="myModal<?php echo $gallerydata->id?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url().'/'.$gallerydata->imagepath;?>" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                        </div>

                         </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>Oops!</strong> No data found , Please insert something to show here.
</div>';
```

**Here is my model**

```
 class Homecontentmodel extends CI_Model
 {


  public function insertslider($bnr)
  {
       return $this->db->insert('slider',$bnr);

  }
  public function fetchsliderimg()
  {
      $q = $this->db->get('slider');

     return $q->result();

  }

 }
```

**Array shown using..Var_dump($galdata);return; in view**
This is the result array after using var dump and return

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[20]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'imagepath' => string 'asset/images/dog-3091075_19201.jpg' (length=34)
      public 'textcontent' => string 'vcbcvbcvbc' (length=10)
      public 'alttext' => string 'dsf' (length=3)
      public 'priority' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[21]
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'imagepath' => string 'asset/images/model.jpg' (length=22)
      public 'textcontent' => string 'xgxfgdf' (length=7)
      public 'alttext' => string 'dgdfgd' (length=6)
      public 'priority' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'imagepath' => string 'asset/images/nomoicard1.jpg' (length=27)
      public 'textcontent' => string 'rtertreerter' (length=12)
      public 'alttext' => string 'dfd' (length=3)
      public 'priority' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: It would help if you could point out which file admin/slidersetting.php is and which is line 90.

Comment: its the first line in view ....... echo   count($galdata);

Comment: in your controller add: $this->load->model('homecontentmodel');

Comment: i have already used it using autoload

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will solve your query :**

Replace

```
if(count($galdata)) {
}
```

with

```
if(! empty($galdata)){
}
```

OR replace with

```
if(count($galdata) > 0) {
}
```

Comment: Oops! No data found , Please insert something to show here.

Comment: how come $galdata is empty

Comment: this is what return empty from database

Comment: but database is not empty

Comment: print and die to check whether data is getting or not, hope this solves ur current problem

Comment: im not getting any data database

Comment: public function fetchsliderimg() { $q = $this->db->get('slider'); return $q->result(); }

Comment: and your table has data? if yes check in the model

Comment: replace this with your model function :  public function fetchsliderimg() 
 { 
    $q = $this->db->get('slider'); 
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    return false; 
}

Comment: same ptoblem again by replacing

Comment: and print_r($galdata) variable in the controller

Comment: this is the first part of your problem second is an another problem, you should ask another question related to your model query

Answer (score 0):

Change like this in controller

```
$galdata['galdata']=$this->homecontentmodel->fetchsliderimg();
$this->load->view('admin/slidersetting',$galdata);
```

The array sign you are using not work in latest php (>5.4) version

Comment: @RigzinAngchok Show your `homecontentmodel` 's `fetchsliderimg()` method

Comment: public function fetchsliderimg()
   {
    $q = $this->db->get('slider');
   return $q->result();
   }

Comment: i have post the model above

Comment: sorry i did not understand?

Comment: @RigzinAngchok put this `<?php var_dump($galdata);return; ?>` in top of your view page and show what it display

Comment: it display  null

Comment: @RigzinAngchok it means there are no data in `slider` table

Comment: yes it gives null  as well as array both what to do now by using  var_dump($galdata);return;

Comment: it gives the array data when return

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your model

```
$this->load->database();
```

Change it  in controller

```
$data['galdata']=$this->homecontentmodel->fetchsliderimg();
// print the query to debug
echo $this->db->last_query();
$this->load->view('admin/slidersetting',$data);
```

Comment: still i have count zero

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();` what is printed?

Comment: cannot see any thing printed